# Running executable after building fails due to not found libraries - how to export paths

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

In my `subdirs`-project I have two libraries and one app that uses those libraries.
The libraries itself use pre-build 3rd party libraries.
My app compiles and links, but fails to run the executable with error `Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?`.

If I navigate to the executable and try to run it, it complains about missing libraries. Then I copy all required libraries into the folder of the executable which now starts when i doubleclick it. Still, QtCreator can not start the executable after building. One of my goals for project setup is **not** to copy files at all, neither headers, nor libs. Headers should be referenced from their source include dir, and libs from their build dir.

I am using `Qt5.3.2` with `qmake` on Windows, using shadowbuilds. I also tried it with Qt5.7. which also could not start my app directly, so it seems not to be a bug. I guess I just don't know how to setup my project correctly.

For building I specify the library paths like `LIBS += -L$${OUT_PWD}/../mylib/debug -lmylib` and it obviously works. 
What options do I have to tell the path of the libraries so that the application starts after building (run from QtCreator), without having to copy all libraries into the executable's folder?

UPDATE:

I went to the RUN-settings of my project in QtCreator and found that the working directory was somehow wrong. I updated it to my shadow build directory. Now, after I copied all dlls, the application can be started by QtCreator. Still, before copying, I get the error `The program has unexpectedly finished`, which is in my experience the typical message for a runtime "I can't find the lib" problem.

Comment: Are you copying .lib files or .dll files?

Comment: I am copying .dll files, I do link dynamically.

Comment: "The program has unexpectedly finished" is code for pretty much every run time error.

Comment: As a general rule, you want to copy the DLLs your application requires, if only to guarantee you have the correct versions in hand and easily found. Counting on them 'being there' runs the risk of not finding them or catching the wrong version if the search order finds the wrong file.

Comment: You are right, of course. But when I get that error, it is **always** the mentioned problem. I must be lucky ;)

Comment: The working directroy of an IDE is rarely the executable folder. Typically it is some neutral folder used by all of the different builds your project may have. This allows you to use the same configuration files, libraries etc... across all of your builds.

Comment: Really? You really would want to duplicate them? Before I changed my setup, I had scripts that I needed to invoke that copied everything to its place. It was a portability and maintenance nightmare. With my subdirs template I am sure that I always have the correct versions. That is the main idea of my setup

Comment: (To be honest, when I made those scripts, I had no clue... I know there are better ways to do the copying)

Comment: The point is you don't duplicate them in the development space. All the development builds use the same copy. As an example, say you switch from the release to the debug and the debug build works because you've got an older config file telling the program to do something different. Not much fun to be had that day.